# Why am I going to get the Hero of Time hat for posting this question?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

The WinterBash site defines [Hero of Time](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/hero-of-time) as follows:

[image]

So why will I win that hat by posting this question, even though it is not "on the hour" right now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Some time zones](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html) have a 30-minute or 45-minute offset, as opposed to using a full hour difference. For instance, when you posted this question at 13:15GMT, it was 22:00 in [Eucla, Australia](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/australia/eucla).

[Nepal](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/nepal/kathmandu) also has a 45-minute offset. It was 19:00 (7:00 PM) in [Kathmandu, Nepal](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/nepal/kathmandu) when you posted this question. So you earned the hat. Thanks, Kathmandu!

If you are interested in this, you can peruse [Time & Date's page on the matter](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html) for more information.